# How is $\frac{\big(\frac{3}{2}\big)^{99}-1}{\big(\frac{3}{2}\big)^{100}-1}\approx\frac{1}{\big(\frac{3}{2}\big)}$

Tags: approximation

I read somewhere that $$\frac{\big(\frac{3}{2}\big)^{99}-1}{\big(\frac{3}{2}\big)^{100}-1}\approx\frac{1}{\big(\frac{3}{2}\big)}$$I don't  know how to have it. Please let me know how this is approximated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another point of view:
$$(3/2)\left((3/2)^{99}-1\right)=(3/2)^{100}-(3/2)=(3/2)^{100}-1-0.5$$

Comment: And the numerator is just $0.5$ less than the denominator, so we get approximation, right?

Comment: @Sush: Yes, but I don't like this approximation.

Comment: Why you don't like it?

Comment: I don't understand how this clarifies the approximation in the question.  @BabakS, could you expand this a bit?

Comment: Nice work, @Babak +1

Comment: @AaronGolden: Personally, I saw your post more descriptive and I posted just an small hint. I don't know why the OP chose mine, however!.

Answer (score 12):

$(3/2)^{99}$ and $(3/2)^{100}$ are both *really* big compared to the $-1$ term in the numerator and the denominator.  So the idea is that you can ignore the $-1$ terms and evaluate the fraction as $(3/2)^{99} / (3/2)^{100} = 1/(3/2)$.

Comment: So quick! Thanks.

Comment: $+1$ for your post.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x>1$ and $q_n = \frac{x^n-1}{x^{n+1}-1}$.

We see that $q_n = \frac{1-\frac{1}{x^n}}{x-\frac{1}{x^n}}$, from which we have $\lim_n q_n = \frac{1}{x}$.

In this case we have $x= \frac{3}{2}$, hence $\lim_n \frac{(\frac{3}{2})^n-1}{(\frac{3}{2})^{n+1}-1} = \frac{1}{(\frac{3}{2})}$.

$n=99$ is sufficiently 'large' that the approximation works.